# Pivot wider in r showing output will contain list-cols

Tags: r, pivot

```
structure(list(appointment_date = structure(c(1658620800, 1658620800, 
                                              1658620800, 1658620800, 1658620800, 1658620800, 1658620800, 1658620800, 
                                              1658620800, 1658620800), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", 
                                                                                                "POSIXt")), last_appointment_date = structure(c(1658620800, 1658620800, 
                                                                                                                                                1658620800, 1658620800, 1656201600, 1658620800, 1659225600, 1658620800, 
                                                                                                                                                1658707200, 1658620800), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                  "POSIXt")), appointment_start_time = c("12:20:00", "10:30:00", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         "14:10:00", "17:20:00", "12:10:00", "10:40:00", "17:30:00", "15:10:00", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         "11:40:00", "10:00:00"), 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               provider = c("Jason", "Jason", "Jason", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        "Jason", "Jason", "Jason", "Jason", "Kevin", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        "Jonathan", "San")), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("tbl_df", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Hi all, a part of my dataset looks like this and I want to use pivot wider to make appointment date as my new name and start time as my value. I used

```
timedata%>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = appointment_date, values_from = appointment_start_time)
```

However, I got a warning: Values are not uniquely identified; output will contain list-cols and the start time value did not show up in each date column. Anyone can help? Thx

Answer (score 1):

Not totally sure what you mean, but `unnest()` after your code will reveal the time.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = appointment_date, 
              values_from = appointment_start_time) %>% 
  unnest()

# A tibble: 10 × 3
   last_appointment_date provider `2022-07-24`
   <dttm>                <chr>    <chr>       
 1 2022-07-24 00:00:00   Jason    12:20:00    
 2 2022-07-24 00:00:00   Jason    10:30:00    
 3 2022-07-24 00:00:00   Jason    14:10:00    
 4 2022-07-24 00:00:00   Jason    17:20:00    
 5 2022-07-24 00:00:00   Jason    10:40:00    
 6 2022-06-26 00:00:00   Jason    12:10:00    
 7 2022-07-31 00:00:00   Jason    17:30:00    
 8 2022-07-24 00:00:00   Kevin    15:10:00    
 9 2022-07-25 00:00:00   Jonathan 11:40:00    
10 2022-07-24 00:00:00   San      10:00:00
```

Comment: Hi, that's exactly what i have to produce. After I added unnest(), it said:
Error: In row 317, can't recycle input of size 5 to size 2.
Warning messages:
1: Values are not uniquely identified; output will contain list-cols.
* Use `values_fn = list` to suppress this warning.
* Use `values_fn = length` to identify where the duplicates arise
* Use `values_fn = {summary_fun}` to summarise duplicates 
2: `cols` is now required when using unnest().
Please use `cols = c(`2022-07-24`, `2022-07-25`, `2022-07-26`, `2022-07-27`, `2022-07-28`, 
    `2022-07-29`, `2022-07-30`, `2022-07-31`)